# Convert a time_period to a date_period

Tags: c++, boost

What's a good way to convert a `time_period` to a `date_period`, e.g. "2015-Apr-25 03:00:00/2015 Apr 27 05:00:00" -> "2015 Apr-25/2015 Apr 27"?  I was hoping one could just use a constructor `date_period(my_time_period_variable)` but that does not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works for me:

```
date_period to_date_period(time_period const& tp) {
    return { tp.begin().date(), tp.end().date() };
}
```

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/0cc3c7e971ebd8bb)</kbd>**

```
#include <boost/date_time/gregorian/gregorian.hpp>
#include <boost/date_time/posix_time/time_period.hpp>
#include <boost/date_time/posix_time/posix_time_io.hpp>

using boost::posix_time::time_period;
using boost::gregorian::date_period;

date_period to_date_period(time_period const& tp) {
    return { tp.begin().date(), tp.end().date() };
}

int main() {
    time_period tp { { {2015, 1, 1}, {10, 13, 0} }, { {2015, 7, 13}, {23, 14, 0} } };
    std::cout << tp << "\n";
    std::cout << to_date_period(tp) << "\n";
}
```

Prints

```
[2015-Jan-01 10:13:00/2015-Jul-13 23:13:59.999999]
[2015-Jan-01/2015-Jul-12]
```